# Center Menu based on width

Tags: html, css, menu

I am building a menu and i'm trying to center the menu based on if the menu link is wider than the menu or menu is wider than the menu link.

At the moment if I add more text to the menu link it wraps onto a new line. So I need to make my menu scalable that If I add more less content to the menu link or the menu itself it will scale accordingly.

HTML

```
<div class="menu-wrap">
    <div class="menu">
        <a href="#">this is a long menu link that wraps<i class="fa fa-chevron-down pl-1" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
    </div>
    <div class="sau-menu"> 
        <ul>
            <li>This is a menu </li>
            <li>This is a menu item</li>
            <li>This is a menu item</li>
            <li>This is a menu item</li>
            <li>This is a menu item</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
```

CSS

```
.menu-wrap{
     position: absolute;
}
.menu{
    position: absolute;
    z-index:3;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    width:100%;
}
.sau-menu {
    z-index:33;
    position: relative;
    top:40px;
    background: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #8e8e8e;
    color:#8e8e8e;
    display:inline-block;
    padding:20px;
    margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
    width:100%;

}

.sau-menu ul{
        list-style: none;
        padding:0;
        margin:0;
        font-size:0.9rem;
}
.sau-menu:after, .sau-menu:before {
    bottom: 100%;
    left: 50%;
    border: solid transparent;
    content: " ";
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    position: absolute;
    pointer-events: none;
}

.sau-menu:after {
    border-bottom-color: #fff;
    border-width: 13px;
    margin-left: -13px;
}
.sau-menu:before {
    border-bottom-color: #8e8e8e;
    border-width: 14px;
    margin-left: -14px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/stevenSAUaa/5sfqp41d/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `.sau-menu padding: 20px` makes the the box **wider** than `.menu-wrap`.

Therefore add `box-sizing: border-box` to `.sau-menu`.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5sfqp41d/1/)